# Rails - Removing a single item from a shopping cart when there are more than one of the same item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through the book Agile Web Development With Rails and I'm stuck on one of the supplementary exercises. The goal is to remove items from a shopping cart, and while I'm able to do this with single items, when there is more than one of an item, it currently erases them all. I want the 'remove item' button to remove only one of the multiple items.

The cart currently looks like this:

item 1 | quantity: 1

item 2 | quantity: 3

So when I click the remove item button on item 2, it currently removes all three of the items, rather than just one. I am trying to accomplish this by decrementing the item's quantity attribute if it's greater than one, rather than deleting it, however it currently does nothing. It still removes it if the quantity is 1. What am I doing incorrectly here?

from line_items_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @cart = @line_item.cart
  if @line_item.quantity > 1 
    @line_item.quantity-=1
  else
    @line_item.destroy
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @cart }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

cart.show.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h2>Your Cart</h2>
<table> 
  <% @cart.line_items.each do |item| %> 
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.quantity %> &times; </td> 
      <td><%= item.product.title %></td> 
      <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
      <td><%= button_to "Remove Item", item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="2">Total</td> 
    <td colspan="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<%= button_to "Empty Cart", @cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are You Sure?' } %>
```

Comment: Your question is not really well formed. What is the real question? Do you need to remove items from the shopping cart or decrease quantity or to delete an item if it's quantity is larger than one? From the code of your view, I see that you want to remove items from the cart... But the rest, I don't understand.

Comment: Where is `@line_item` set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't committing the change to quantity to the database. You need add something like:

```
@line_item.save
```

So then your code would look like:

```
def destroy
  @cart = @line_item.cart
  if @line_item.quantity > 1 
    @line_item.quantity-=1
    @line_item.save
  else
    @line_item.destroy
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @cart }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help @mxvx. The way it's written now when you get down to zero from more than one, you'll have to remove the line_item twice because the first time it will save the quantity as zero and then the second time it will actually destroy it.

Comment: just use:
 if @line_item.quantity >= 2